# How to apply the :not selector

Tags: css, overriding

I am using sapui5 where all the tables are preformatted 
with SAP's css classes.

I have my own table where I want to remove all borders .
The table is designed with the id selector.

My question: how am I to remove SAP's class restraint 
so that only my table is excluded from this class 
attributes

e.g

```
#myTableClass :not .SAPClass>tr
{
border : 0px !important;
}
```

All other tables in my HTML doc should go
on inherting SAP's original class attributes.

Any suugestion will be highly appreciated

rgds
Yuval

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: are you trying to do something like:  `#myTableClass:not(.SAPClass) > tr`  or what?  I dont know what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi I am tring to applying no borders on on table where the whole document is preformatted with SAP class. this class lookes like .tablecls>tr

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to apply no borders on the table, do this:

```
.your-class-name {
  border: none !important;
}
```